# Are Devanagari letters R and S related?

Tags: devanagari

Devanagari letter र (R, more precisely *ra* in IAST or ISO 15919) and letter स (S, *sa*) are somewhat similar. The similarity is more apparent when comparing ***rā*** with ***sa***:

[image: Devanagari rā sa]

What is the history and nature of this similarity (if not random)?

Answer (score 6):

Earlier forms of the script such as Brahmi  = r,  = s as well as related script (Gurmukhi ਰ = r, ਸ = s), reveal that it is a coincidence. It is interesting to note that Tibetan ར = r, ས = s which are are significantly similar to Devanagari, but Bengali
র = r, স = s which are not so similar. Yet Tibetan and Bengali scripts are classified as examples of [Siddham scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddha%E1%B9%83_script). The drawings in that page suggest that the seeds of similarity were present in that script, and developed independently in Devanagari and Tibetan.

Comment: that's Bengali *so/sho*, with an inherent vowel (the downstroke, cp. Arab. *alef*: "l"). The *cho/so* looks like a mirrored *ri*, whereas *bho* looks just like *ri* without the dot, and what would look like Devanagari *Ra* is actually *ho* (/ɦɔ~hɔ/). In the Siddham script, the horizontal stroke seen in *Sa* appears frequently to symbolize voicing or breathy voice (eg. *jho*), and there's a bare *r* marked by a ... dangling stroke. In Tibetan, *Om* is written in a conjunction of strokes: seems to contain syllabic *r* or *h*? This looks completely arbitrary, yes, still fascinating.